# Correct way to unblock a kernel thread

Tags: c, linux, kernel

There are linux kernel threads that do some work every now and then, then either go to sleep or block on a semaphore. They can be in this state for several seconds - quite a long time for a thread.
If threads need to be stopped for some reason, at least if unloading the driver they belong to, I am looking for a way to get them out of sleep or out of the semaphore without waiting the whole sleep time or triggering the semaphore as often as required.

I found and read a lot about this but there are multiple advises and I am still not sure how things work. So if you could shed some light on that.

#### msleep_interruptible

What is able to interrupt that?

#### down_interruptible

This semaphore function implies interrupt-ability. Same here, what can interrupt this semaphore?

#### kthread_stop

It's described as *sets kthread_should_stop to true and wakes it...* but this function blocks until the sleep time is over (even if using msleep_interruptible) or the semaphore is triggered.
What am I understanding wrong?

#### Use a signal to unblock - really?

My search found a signal can interrupt the thread. Other hits say a signal is not the best way to operate on threads.

If a signal is the best choice - which signal do I use to unblock the thread but not mess it up too much?
SIGINT is a termination signal - I don't intend to terminate something, just make it go on.

### More information

The threads run a loop that checks a termination flag, does some work and then block in a sleep or a semaphore. They are used for

Situation 1.
A producer-consumer scenario that uses semaphores to synchronize producer and consumer. They work perfectly to make threads wait for work and start running on setting the semaphore.

Currently I'm setting a termination flag, then setting the semaphore up. This unblocks the thread which then checks the flag and terminates. This isn't my major problem. Hovever of course I'd like to know about a better way.

Code sample

```
while (keep_running) {
  do_your_work();
  down_interruptible(&mysemaphore); // Intention: break out of this
}
```

Situation 2.
A thread that periodically logs things. This thread sleeps some seconds between doing it's work. After setting the flag this thread terminates at it's next run but this can take several seconds. I want to break the sleep if necessary.

Code sample

```
while (keep_running) {
  do_your_work();
  msleep(15000); // Intention: break out of this - msleep_interruptible?
}
```

Comment: Please, provide more background of **your task**. It is better to include some code *samples*, which demonstrates your intention. You ask about interrupts and their ability to interrupt waiting state of a *specific* sync object. But main intention of interrupts is awoke the thread from *any* of such sync object. If you know which sync object the threads awaits, it is better to awoke the thread using an operations of that sync object, not interrupts. It smells you have a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so it is better to describe original one

Comment: I added more information about how I use the threads. You are right, what I'm missing is the proper way to unblock the threads' waiting states. I simply don't know how exactly. The word interrupt isn't meant to be a software interrupt or something. I used it in context of the funcion msleep_interruptible which suggests one can somehow interrupt=stop it. Code samples are provided although they are really simpel,

Comment: Showing the code is nice, but the problem is still not clear. The thread waits (for example) on the semaphore for a purpose. **Why** do you want to awoke it? Do you want a thread to go into the **next cycle**? If so, release the semaphore - this is exactly what the thread waits. Or do you want to **terminate** the thread (by setting `keep_running` variable to FALSE before)?

Comment: @Tsyvarev oops ... This seems to have got lost while composing my question. I want to unblock the threads in order to terminate them. That means get them unblocked right now regardless of semaphores or sleeping time.